# Htc one m9 unable to find firmware files for update from Android 5 to 6

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow

I bought a Htc one M9, and flashed Viperone m9 Marshmallow without first update the Stock rom to Marshmallow, and got stuck in bootloader.
Flashed Viper Lollipop, and the phone works again, but now i can't update, because i haven't got a clue which firmware files i should flash, i have found quite a lot of them, and i don't want to brick the darn thing, but i want my Marshmallow..
Could anyone throw me a bone here?
This is my info from the phone:

kernel: lk
product: htc_himauhl
version: 1.0
imei:
version-main: 1.32.401.15
boot-mode: download
version-bootloader: 1.0.0.0000
mid: 0PJA10000
cid: HTC__Y13

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you list the names and file extensions of the marshmallow firmware files please?

Comment: I figured it out with some help from the guys on Xda.  just had to og s:off and flash firmware 3.35.401.12, reinstall Viper, and voila :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check wich firmware version your rom needs. For latest viperonem9 it's 3.35.401.12.

Now you can go to the xda-developer page http://forum.xda-developers.com/one-m9/development/firmware-t3068243 to find the latest htc firmwares for the m9 with a detailed guide.

Be aware that the fullstock firmwares force a full wipe, so you will lose your data. To avoid that you can use the nowipe firmwares wich are linked on the same page.

Comment: Thank you,, that was exactly what i did,, got som help from the guys on Xda, and learned a bit in the process  :)